# Row level security + Switch statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, row-level-security

I've a big table with lot of data who needs to have some RLS security.

The RLS is based on an other table (user logins with a profile number).

I've to make different logic of filtering depending on the profile number...

Let's say if the userProfile is 1 he can see all data. 
If the user profile is 2 he can only see the data based on `colA` if he's 3 it's `colB` who have to be checked.

Example :

```
Profile | login               Data | colA |  colB
   2    |  toto               data | toto |  tutu
   3    |  tutu               data | tata |  tutu
```

I've tried to create a `Switch` statement based on `profileType` but it doesn't work. And i don't know if we can return a filtering in switch.

My try :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_rls_users](@username AS VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS TABLE 
with schemabinding
AS 
RETURN (
    SELECT Department,ProfileType, 
        CASE 
           WHEN ProfileType = 1 THEN 
           RETURN (
              SELECT 1 AS [fn_rls_users] 
              FROM BIG_TABLE
           )
           WHEN ProfileType = 2 THEN 
           RETURN (
              SELECT 1 AS [fn_rls_users] 
              FROM BIG_TABLE
              WHERE Department = Department
           )
           ELSE (
              SELECT 0 AS [fn_rls_users] 
              FROM BIG_TABLE
           )
        END
    FROM dbo.UserProfiles WHERE UserLogin = @username
)

GO
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ProfileType date = (SELECT ProfileType FROM dbo.UserProfiles WHERE UserLogin = @username)

if @ProfileType = 1
select isnull(Data, 'NaN') from BIG_TABLE

else if @ProfileType = 2
select isnull(Data, 'NaN') from BIG_TABLE where colA = @username

else
select isnull(Data, 'NaN') from BIG_TABLE where colB = @username

End
```

Or, if you like using str exec

```
DECLARE @ProfileType date = (SELECT ProfileType FROM dbo.UserProfiles WHERE UserLogin = @username)

declare @str_sql varchar(1000)

set @str_sql = 'select isnull(Data, "NaN") from BIG_TABLE'

if @ProfileType = 2
set @str_sql += ' where colA = ' + @username

else if @ProfileType = 3
set @str_sql += ' where colB = ' + @username
exec(@str_sql)
```

Comment: Thanks, got errors on your version. `No column was specified for column 3  of fn_rls_users`

Comment: @Alexis I think I misunderstand ur question, wait, I answer it again simply base on ur example.